# Singularity container -B not found

Tags: shell, singularity-container

I changed the I am running the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
#SBATCH --job-name psy-bkeeser_fmriprep
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --mem=32GB
#SBATCH --output /projects/core-psy/logs/nako/stephan/slurm-%j.log
#SBATCH --error /projects/core-psy/logs/nako/stephan/slurm-%j.err

singularity run --pwd /tmp3 \
--home /projects/core-psy/tmp3:/home/fmriprep \
--cleanenv \
-B /projects/core-psy/data/nako/swunderl/pa/BIDS_DATA/:/input \
-B /projects/core-psy/data/nako/bkeeser/test:/output \
-B /projects/core-psy/data/nako/bkeeser/freesurfer:/freesurfer \
-B /projects/core-psy/tmp:/opt/templateflow \
/projects/core-psy/images/nipreps-fmriprep-21.0.1.simg /input /output participant \
--fs-license-file /freesurfer/license.txt \
--skip-bids-validation \
--fs-no-reconall \
```

This gives me an error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
>     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/work/20220312-010716_89e666a8-3458-4f82-9ff2-b13ef397a3b4/bids_db'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/opt/conda/bin/fmriprep", line 8, in <module>
>     sys.exit(main())
>   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fmriprep/cli/run.py", line 38,
> ```
>
> in main
> parse_args()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fmriprep/cli/parser.py", line
> 679, in parse_args
> config.from_dict(vars(opts))
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fmriprep/config.py", line 666,
> in from_dict
> execution.load(settings)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fmriprep/config.py", line 238,
> in load
> cls.init()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fmriprep/config.py", line 465,
> in init
> _db_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1292, in mkdir
> self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
> self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/work/20220312-010716_89e666a8-3458-4f82-9ff2-b13ef397a3b4'

sth seems to be wrong with the tmp folder?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use comments like this when splitting a command across multiple lines. The shell is interpreting `-B` as a another command, not as an argument to `singularity`.

One solution is to remove the commented lines altogher. You can put them above or below the command, but not inside the command.

Answer (score 0):

The --pwd /tmp3 argument points to a directory that does not seem to exist from the context of your run command. If you remove this, you may have success binding the other directories.

If this does not resolve the error, you might want to try switching from --home to mounting a writeable folder to /opt/templateflow and setting the TEMPLATEFLOW_HOME variable in your run command as suggested here: https://www.nipreps.org/apps/singularity/#templateflow-and-singularity